# Project developed in .Net framework 2.0 (NOT .net core 2.0) in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-2.0

I have to troubleshoot a old project developed 10 years back in .Net framework 2.0. I have visual studio 2017 installed on my windows 10 laptop. 
I am getting following error while opening .vb [Design] file:

"Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v2.0'. This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework moniker is incorrectly formatted. "
Note: I have manually installed .net framework 2.0

Kindly help to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!